# SQL Server : change column to not null in a very large table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-express

I am trying to change a column to `not null` on a 3.5 gb table (SQL Server Express).

All rows contain values in the table.

I remove the check box from `allow null` and click save.

I get:

> Unable to modify table.
>   Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might not work directly. You need to do it in this way

First make all the NULL values in your table non null

```
UPDATE tblname SET colname=0 WHERE colname IS NULL
```

Then update your table

```
ALTER TABLE tblname ALTER COLUMN colname INTEGER NOT NULL
```

Hope this solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can also increase or override the timeout.

1. In SQL Server Managment Studio, click Tools->Options
2. Expand "Designers" and select "Table and Database Designers" on left (see pic)
3. From here you have the option to override the timeout or increase it:

   - Increase your "Transaction time-out after:" (see pic)

     OR
   - Uncheck "Override connection string time-out value for table designer updates:"

[image]

The default timeout is 30 seconds as you can see. These options are documented on [MS Support page here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/915849).

Answer (score 2):

Try this one :

```
 ALTER TABLE tblname ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_tblname_colnamename] DEFAULT (0) FOR  colname
 ALTER TABLE tblname ALTER COLUMN colname INTEGER  NOT NULL
```